# WordPress - hide an element on every page except one

Tags: css, wordpress, display

I activated an option to display a short description on my WordPress site.
The thing is that I want this description only on 1 page but it displays on all of the pages.

So I added this CSS:

```
.page-id-1234 {display: none;}
```

on the pages that I don't want my text to display on. But my question is:

Is there a way to hide this text on every page except the one that I want it to display on, instead of putting `display: none;` on all of my other pages?

Comment: Sure; `:not()` springs to mind. In what way is the page you want to show it on different?

Comment: use this selector `body:not(.page-id-11) { }` .. you can read about the not() selector

Comment: I don't want to hide on one page , I want to display just on one page and hide on other. But if there is a way to avoid to add css with all the page-id , it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Since every page has a specific ID you would have to set the elements **default** `display` property value to `none` and **override** this for your specific page ID.

So let's say your element has an ID of `#description`

You would set this to

```
#description {
    display:none;
}
```

then add a line referencing the page ID as higher specificity selector and change the display property as required

```
#page-id-1234 #description {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it on just one page then you can use `:not()` css selector

```
:not(.page-id-1234) {display: None;}
```

This way it will be hidden on every page which does not have `.page-id-1234` class.